# What is the correct way to use the elasticsearch-dsl Percolate query?

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-py, elasticsearch-dsl-py

```
s = Search(index='test-index').using(client)
q = Q('percolate',
            field="query",
            documents=list_of_documents)
s = s.query(q)
p = s.execute()
```

I am attempting to run a percolation query against an index, with a list of documents and I am getting the error

`RequestError(400, 'search_phase_execution_exception', 'Field [_id] is a metadata field and cannot be added inside a document. Use the index API request parameters.').`

Any help solving this is very much appreciated.

Comment: Please share an example of the list of documents you are sending to the query.

Comment: @KevinQuinzel The list is a list of elastic documents, so a list of dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

I'll start to explain this via the APIs.

The [Percolate query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-percolate-query.html) can be used to match queries stored in an index.

When creating an index with a Percolate field, you specify a mapping like this:

```
PUT /my-index
{
    "mappings": {
         "properties": {
             "message": {
                 "type": "text"
             },
             "query": {
                 "type": "percolator"
             }
        }
    }
}
```

This indicates that the field `message` will be the one used for the Percolate query.

If you would like to match a list of documents, a list of terms with this field should be sent like in the [example found in the docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-percolate-query.html#_percolating_multiple_documents):

```
GET /my-index/_search
{
    "query" : {
        "percolate" : {
            "field" : "query",
            "documents" : [ 
                {
                    "message" : "bonsai tree"
                },
                {
                    "message" : "new tree"
                },
                {
                    "message" : "the office"
                },
                {
                    "message" : "office tree"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Said this, you should:

1. Set the proper mappings in your ES index to Percolate a specific field.
2. In the DSL, send the list of parameters only with the "Percolated" field, instead of the whole ES document.

Hope this is helpful :D

Comment: I am able to do this with the ES API no problem, but the issue is recreating this exact function but using the Python `elasticsearch-dsl` library.